# Probability independent event

Tags: probability-theory

On a day at the races, the probability that an event is won by a mare is 53.6%,
while the probability that the winner is a three-year-old is 61.2% . What is
the probability that a three-year-old mare will win if there is a 67.4% chance
that the winner is either a mare or a three-year-old?

My approach below
P(A∩B)=P(A)P(B) =32.8%

Comment: Where on Earth did you see a hypothesis stating that you could assume that A and B are independent? Please read seriously what is given to you (and nothing else).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you assumed that A and B are independent events. 
Let's assume that $P(A)$ represents the probability of a mare winning, while $P(B)$ represents the probability of a three year old winning. Now, we know: $$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$
$P(A \cup B)$ will represent the probability of either a mare winning or a three year old winning (union represents or) while $P(A \cap B)$ represents the probability of a three year old mare winning. We can now substitute the given values to obtain the answer.